# CustomPropertyEditor in Grails

Tags: grails, propertyeditor

I have a Grails (version 2.5.0 ; Groovy version 2.4.3) application where I had a CustomPropertyEditorRegistry to override date formats when using `fieldvalue`.

I installed ElasticSerach Grails plugin version 0.0.4.4 , after installation I noticed the custom property editor was not working anymore (rolled back with no code change and it works again).

The property editor is for Date values being rendered in a specific format. The issue arrises when a user submits a form with a date (a JavaScript date picker ensure the format on selection) and a validation error occurs on the backend. When the form is rendered with the errors list, the dates are rendered as the default format: `Fri Jun 12 12:36:02 EDT 2015`

I'd like to know how I can fix the property editor or another best practice for this type of use case.

UPDATE:
Here's a sample app that demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/bwagner5/grailsElasticSearchPropertyEditorSample

Comment: Can you describe how it is that you are rendering the date?

Comment: Oh, I think I see now.  You are using `fieldValue`.

Comment: CustomPropertyEditor is applicable through out the application. You can use [`@BindingFormat`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/api/org/grails/databinding/BindingFormat.html) instead, which is a fine grained approach to avoid interfering other date bindings.